Using Cython in Pycharm Jupyter Notebook gives unresolved reference
As you can see, Pycharm is giving me "Unresolved Reference" error when I am using Jupyter Notebook. However, the code runs fine. It's just that the red line is annoying,
And the code cell below the cython cell gets unreachable code warning:
enter image description here
The red lines and yellow lines should be gone

The image you included in support doesn't match what your text says. Also please read How do I ask a good question? especially under 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it says, "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. " You can use an image in support for something hard to describe but have described in text, too. Pus have code in post. This is ...

 you want things to be linkable and searchable so that your post is useful to others in similar situation. Or you can find your own issue a year from now when perhaps you are trying to recall how you solved an issue.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
